# Virtual columns in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

Is it possible to add a virtual column to a model (not virtual attribute!)?

I have following situation:
A `Product(id, name)` has many `ProductVariant(id, price, offer_price, product_id,...)`

When I select all products I want to have the minimum product price from all `ProductVariants` in the products result.

```
@products = Product.with_min_price.order('min_price ASC')
```

I calculate the minimum price in a sql query (`with_min_price`) and want to add this `min_price` value to each `Product` in my `@products result`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could just be a method in your Product class assuming your Product has_many ProductVarients

```
#Product Model

def min_product_price
  product_variants.map(&:price).min
end
```

Comment: Should that be `def self.min_product_price` if it's a class method?

Comment: whoops, yeah, that's not a class method, it's a method on the object. I updated the answer. You'd just call call ` @products.each {|p| p.min_product_price } `

Comment: Thanks. I added the class method to my model. This works find

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a custom select, though the column will be read-only:

```
>> order = Order.find(:first, :select => "(id+111) as order_number")
=> #<Order order_number: "119"
>> order.order_number
=> "119"
```

You can also use the new column as you would a calculated column in SQL in any of the other parts of a find or the Rails 3 equivalents.

Comment: Thanks. I found one solution that works.
The problem was that I use a SQL min with a group by to calculate the minimum price.
If I have this query Category.last.products.with_min_price.order('category_products.position') the position is missing in selects. So I have to add it in this query. with_min_price(:and => 'position')